# How to Vertically Center Arrow?

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, tikz-trees

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{HEAPIFY(A, 7)}\\
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node{4}
            child { node {21} }
            child { node {14} };
          \end{tikzpicture}
          $\rightsquigarrow$
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node{21}
            child { node {4} }
            child { node {14} };
          \end{tikzpicture}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The above code results in this output:

[image]

I want to vertically center the arrow based on the total height of the graphs (not of the height of 14 and 4). How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options, the perhaps simplest ones are

1. set the `baseline` of the `tikzpicture`s appropriately, or
2. use `remember picture` to add an `overlay` path that contains the arrow.

The first two examples set the baseline of the diagrams to the bottom nodes, the other two examples to the center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{HEAPIFY(A, 7)}\\
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(14.base)}]
            \node{4}
            child { node {21} }
            child { node (14){14} };
          \end{tikzpicture}
          $\rightsquigarrow$
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(14.base)}]
            \node{21}
            child { node {4} }
            child { node (14){14} };
          \end{tikzpicture}
    \item \textbf{HEAPIFY(A, 7)}\\
          \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \node{4}
            child { node {21} }
            child { node (14){14} };
          \end{tikzpicture}
          $\hphantom{\rightsquigarrow}$
          \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \node{21}
            child { node (4) {4} }
            child { node {14} };
            \path[overlay] (14) -- node{$\rightsquigarrow$}(4);
          \end{tikzpicture}

    \item \textbf{HEAPIFY(A, 7)}\\
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(aux.base)}]
            \node (4) {4}
            child { node {21} }
            child { node (14){14} };
            \path (4) -- node(aux){\vphantom{x}}(14) ;
          \end{tikzpicture}
          $\rightsquigarrow$
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(aux.base)}]
            \node(21){21}
            child { node {4} }
            child { node (14){14} };
            \path (21) -- node(aux){\vphantom{x}} (14) ;
          \end{tikzpicture}
    \item \textbf{HEAPIFY(A, 7)}\\
          \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \node(4){4}
            child { node {21} }
            child { node (14){14} };
          \end{tikzpicture}
          $\hphantom{\rightsquigarrow}$
          \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
            \node(21){21}
            child { node (4') {4} }
            child { node {14} };
            \path[overlay] (4) --  node(aux1){\vphantom{x}}(14)
            (21) --  node(aux2){\vphantom{x}} (4')
             (aux1) -- node{$\rightsquigarrow$}(aux2);
          \end{tikzpicture}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I think I've not explained in enough detail. I meant the arrow to be in the center of the graph's total height (not of 14 and 4). That's my fault, sorry!

Comment: @FlorianLudewig I added this case, too. The lower two examples do that.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!